# SearchView Edittext not showing cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, searchview

I am unable to show cursor on the edittext of searchview following is the code i am trying to implement but of no use

```
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    final int textViewID = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    final EditText searchTextView = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(textViewID);
    try {
        Field mCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        mCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
        mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, null); //This sets the cursor resource ID to 0 or @null which will make it visible on white background
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

I even tried the code below but even this doesnt seem to work.

```
EditText searchTextView = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchTextView.setFocusable(true);
searchTextView.setCursorVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

what is your color accent in the style theme? and what is the background of the search field?

Try using a custom drawable

```
    mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, R.drawable.cursor);
```

cursor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
<size android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: bro my accent color was wrong but the problem is still the same i have to keep the accent color to what it is..

Comment: In My case my accent color and searchview background was same, so my cursor was not visible. I used this custom cursor drawable and it was visible then.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Edittext in xml.

```
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
    android:background="@drawable/R.drawable.selfbg"/>
```

Than create drawalble xml: color_cursor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000000"  />
</shape>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the code line `mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, null);` Because if you set the drawable to cursor after the this line it will not set correctly. so please remove that line and add this `mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, R.drawable.cursor);` with custom cursor drawable.