# SearchView cursor not visible

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, searchview

The cursor inside my searchview is not visible. how can i make it visible?

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/edit_query"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@color/app_dark_color"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:queryHint="@string/search"
    app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_ricerca"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor"
    tools:text="Name" />
```

Comment: Explain what have you tried to make it work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284978/searchview-edittext-not-showing-cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reviewed your question and the same problem that we had encountered in the past. One of the solutions we have tried has resolved our problem. Please try with that solution it may solve your issue.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView    
android:id="@+id/edit_query"    
android:layout_width="0dp"    
android:layout_height="50dp"    
android:background="@android:color/white"    
android:ems="10"    
android:importantForAutofill="no"    
android:inputType="text"    
android:textColor="#ff0000"    
android:textStyle="bold"    
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"    
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"    
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"    
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:queryHint="Search"
tools:ignore="LabelFor"
android:theme="@style/searchViewTheme"
tools:text="Name" />
```

style.xml

```
    <style name="searchViewTheme"parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You solved my problem! A thousand thanks!

Comment: cheers happy cooding